# Is it possible to backport "yield_self" to Ruby versions prior to 2.5?

Tags: ruby

I have a legacy app that "can not be upgraded" and I'm missing the `yield_self` feature from more recent Ruby versions.

Is there a way to backport it to(use it in) Ruby version prior to 2.5?

An example:

```
"data.csv"
  .yield_self { |name| File.expand_path(name, __dir__) }
  .yield_self { |path| File.read(path) }
  .yield_self { |body| CSV.parse(body) }
  .map        { |row|  row[1].to_i }
  .sum
```

Comment: There's the [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem. Just `require 'backports/2.5.0/kernel/yield_self'` and you should be good to go. The implementation is [here](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/2.5.0/kernel/yield_self.rb)

Comment: @Stefan nice. If you would like to post your comment as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I think your answer (with actual code) is better than a link to a gem.

Comment: Many SO members--including @Stefan, I expect--are unwilling to post an answer that merely provides a link (or an answer they regard as trivial).

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods:

1. Without using third-party gems, add the following snippet somewhere in your project:

```ruby
current_version = Gem::Version.new(RUBY_VERSION)
yield_self_introduced_in_version = Gem::Version.new('2.5.0')

if current_version < yield_self_introduced_in_version
  class Object
    def yield_self
      yield self
    end
  end
else
  warn "yield_self backport method is no longer needed. Delete it"
end
```

See [alternative slightly more advanced implementation](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/blob/master/lib/backports/2.5.0/kernel/yield_self.rb) from the backports gem

---

2. Use [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem

And require it explicitly:

```ruby
require 'backports/2.5.0/kernel/yield_self'
```

Comment: why `*args`? `yield_self` doesn't accept any args, does it?

Comment: Personally, I prefer the alias `then`. `"data.csv".then{...}.then{...}`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're right, yield_self doesn't accept any arguments from what I see in the ruby/ruby repository. I've updated the answer